# Why gridlines is shortcuted in cartopy GeoAxes?

Tags: python, cartopy

I can't draw full length gridlines in cartopy, but instead shortcut ones. Let's see an example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
from cartopy.mpl.gridliner import LONGITUDE_FORMATTER, LATITUDE_FORMATTER

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,6))
ax = plt.subplot(111, projection=ccrs.Mercator())
ax.coastlines()
ax.set_extent([119, 125, 38, 42], crs=ccrs.PlateCarree())

gl = ax.gridlines(ccrs.PlateCarree(), xlocs=[121, 123], 
                  ylocs=[39.5, 40.5], linestyle='--', 
                  color='r', alpha=1, draw_labels=True)
gl.xformatter = LONGITUDE_FORMATTER
gl.yformatter = LATITUDE_FORMATTER
plt.show()
```

The result figure would be something like:
[image: output of the code]

I suppost I will get gridlines extended from left (or bottom) to right (or top) spines. But as you can see, the gridlines are short cutted to a rectangle.

- How can I get "full length" gridlines?
- And by `color='r', alpha=1`, why can't I get a `red, un-transparent` gridline?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Q1. How can I get "full length" gridlines?

Declare ranges of `xlocs`, `ylocs` to extend beyond the display limits.

Q2. By color='r', alpha=1, why can't I get a red, un-transparent gridline?

The default line width is so thin to show the real color. Declare thicker linewidth's value as you need.

Full working code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
from cartopy.mpl.gridliner import LONGITUDE_FORMATTER, LATITUDE_FORMATTER

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,6))
ax = plt.subplot(111, projection=ccrs.Mercator())
ax.coastlines()
ax.set_extent([119, 125, 38, 42], crs=ccrs.PlateCarree())

gl = ax.gridlines(ccrs.PlateCarree(), \
                  xlocs=[100, 121, 123, 130],  \
                  ylocs=[20, 39.5, 40.5, 60], \
                  linestyle='--', 
                  color='r', alpha=1, linewidth=1, draw_labels=True)
gl.xformatter = LONGITUDE_FORMATTER
gl.yformatter = LATITUDE_FORMATTER
plt.show()
```

Resulting map:

[image]